# Insert & Delete values in many to many relation table

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I want to insert values to many to many relation table 
I'm using entity framework & linq. and I want to build up the Insert query (.net Framework 4)

following are the tables

Menus -
    menu_id,
    menu_name,
    menu_desc

Cater  - cater_id,
           cater_name, 
           enable_ind

Relation table
Menu_Cater -    menu_id,
                    cater_id

I have tried with couple of cases seems not working, 
if there is a SIMPLE way of implementing this insert & delete

Comment: what have you tried? my initial GUESS without seeing any of your code, is that `menu_id` and `cater_id` are auto-incrementing fields and you are trying to insert a `Menu_Cater` record before inserting the `Menu` and `Cater` records. Thus, inserting a `Menu_Cater` record with `menu_id` and `cater_id` set to `NULL`. Stab in the dark - show me your code!

Comment: can you some of the cases/code so we can check

Comment: @Sethi Actually I have two drop downs to select cater and menu and I want to save the selected combination in the Menu_Cater.

Comment: Are you using DbContext to persist the objects to database?

Comment: I'm using EF4, its same as this case    http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/entity-framework-queries-involving-many-to-many-relationship-tables/      But i need to know how can I do the  Insert and delete

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the `Menu` and `Cater` objects (from the dropdown list or however), simply:

1. create a `Menu_Cater` record
2. set it to insert on submit
3. submit changes

Demonstrated below:

**VB.NET**

```
Dim menu As Menu = GetSelectedMenu() ' However you get the Menu record
Dim cater As Cater = GetSelectedCater() ' However you get the Cater record

Dim relationship = New Menu_Cater()
' EITHER:
relationship.menu_id = menu.menu_id
relationship.cater_id = cater.cater_id
' OR:
' relationship.menu = menu
' relationship.cater = cater

Using db = new MyDataContext
    db.Menu_Cater.InsertOnSubmit( relationship )
    db.SubmitChanges()
End Using
```

**C#**

```
Menu menu = GetSelectedMenu(); // However you get the Menu record
Cater cater = GetSelectedCater(); // However you get the Cater record

Menu_Cater relationship = new Menu_Cater();
// EITHER:
relationship.menu_id = menu.menu_id;
relationship.cater_id = cater.cater_id;
// OR:
// relationship.menu = menu
// relationship.cater = cater

using (db = new MyDataContext()) {
    db.Menu_Cater.InsertOnSubmit(relationship);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Small changes may need to be made for your variable/database-field names. And maybe `db.Save()` instead of `db.SubmitChanges()` depending on the type of data context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if You need it now, but Ill show how to do it.
If I have understood right, You mean smth like that.

```
public ActionResult Create(Cater cater, int menuId)
{
    //Find menu with our menu_id
    Menu menu = db.Menus.Where(m => m.menu_id == menuId).FirstOrDefault();

    //Add cater for this Menu
    menu.Cater.Add(cater);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return somethere...
}

public ActionResult Remove(int caterId, int menuId)
{
 //Choose menu, from him we will delete cater which we need 
 Menu menu = db.Menus.Where(m => m.menu_id == menuId).FirstOrDefault();

 //Find cater which we want delete from this Menu
 Cater cater = menu.Cater.Where(c => c.cater_id == caterId).FirstOrDefault();

 //Remove him from Table Menu_Cater
 menu.Cater.Remove(cater);
 db.SaveChanges();

 return somethere...
}
```

Thats all. Its work for MVC4